# Mock json structure with image srces and reach the images inside React file locally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

I want to make a little shopping app with an array of items that is in the store. I am thinking of something like:

`// Inside MyStore/index.js const storeItems = [{ src: '../../images/football.jpg', title: 'Football' }, { src: '../../images/basketball.jpg', title: 'Basketball' }];`

And think that I have this folder structure:

`/images/football.jpg`

`/components/MyStore/index.js`

I have also tried to put the `images` folder inside a public folder (?) and tried to reference that, but I could not reach the image. Perhaps that was not "configured right", if I need to do anything else than just have a folder named `public`? Maybe I need to do anything inside webpack configuration? I am using create-react-app, so I guess this sets it all up for me.

I tried to add like width and height to the image tag, to make it bigger than the 0x0 I got, but it did not help.

I tried something like this `<image src={storeItems[0].src} width="100" height="100" />`.

How can I make this work?

I know that I could have imported the two images into the React-file, like this and used it directly inside the image-tag:
`import footballSrc from '../../images/football.jpg'; <image src={fotballSrc} />`

But that is not what I want. I want to be able to mock a json-file with all the image src inside it.

Answer (score 0):

i think that you should map your array and require images like the example above

[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-hamilton-0q5ts?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Now I do not know how this would work, but if I had an API that returned a JSON-structure with that array, I probably would have to make this work somehow, since I can not include images based on the response from that API.

And If I should not mock this, I do not know if you should store images inside the database, or inside something else (I read something about file storage). If you have a good solution, please tell me about it